# Lookup field in restApi

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I try to make a restApi call for create. One field in this Object is a lookup field.

How is the syntax to make an api call with a lookup field in the iOS Salesforce MobileSDK?

I tried:

```swift
request = restAPI.requestForCreate(withObjectType: "Z_Product_Line_Item__c", fields: ["z_request__c": caseID,
                                                                                              "Z_Product__r": ["Product2.Z_R3_Material_no__c" : "A1672SO"],
                                                                                              "Z_Amount__c": 4,
                                                                                              "z_delivery_unit__c": "pcs"])
```

I get this error:

> JSON_PARSER_ERROR

If i try:

```swift
request = restAPI.requestForCreate(withObjectType: "Z_Product_Line_Item__c", fields: ["z_request__c": caseID,
                                                                                              "Z_Product__r": "Product2.Z_R3_Material_no__c: A1672SO", //the row for question
                                                                                              "Z_Amount__c": 4,
                                                                                              "z_delivery_unit__c": "pcs"])
```

Then I get this error:

> The value provided for foreign key reference Z_Product__r is not a nested SObject

edit: added the hole syntax

Answer (score 2):

An object in JSON is surrounded by `{}`, not `[]` (which is an array). The following change should work:

```
"Z_Product__r": {"Z_R3_Material_no__c" : "A1672SO"}
```

This answer presumes that the named field is an External ID field.

Comment: thanks for the response. But if I would you use json in ajax than this would work, but I need the syntax for the iOS SDK in swift. I updated my question with the hole syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Lookup fields contain the `Id` of the associated record. So if your field name is `Z_Product__c`, then you will need to have the `Id` of the record in your JSON body to which you need the newly created record to be associated to, sample below:

```
"Z_Product__c" : "Id of the record"
```

The other syntax that you have will work, if you have an *External Id* field on your lookup object, then you can utilize that field without using the Id values. E.g., say `Ext_Id__c` was a field on your `Z_Product__c` object and has value say `123`, then you can use that field's value while creating your record as below:

```
"Z_Product__r" :
{
     "Ext_Id__c" : 123
}
```

You can find more details on operations using [external id here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated my answer with the hole syntax. My problem is that I need the syntax for a nested SObject in Swift. I tried as well to type just the recordId, as you recomended, but this does not work. The error message is: "The value provided for foreign key reference Z_Product__r is not a nested SObject"

Comment: You cannot use the `Id` value on `__r`. `__r` is used to denote the relationship name. You will need to find out what is that in your case.